# How do I access DispatcherServlet with MockMvc?

Tags: junit4, spring-test

I have a basic SpringMVC Application which is running (and mapping) fine.
Now I wanted to set up my UnitTests with MockMvc to perform get requests and stuff.
But if I run the test there is an AssertionError "Status expected: <200> but was: <404>" and my console gives warning "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name ''".
I get the feeling my MockMvc cant communicate with my DispatcherServlet, so how do I define this connection?

Here is my short test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class HomeControllerTest {

  private MockMvc mvc;
  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws ServletException {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testLandingPagePath() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

So I expected MockMvc to get the location of my DispatcherServlet by default. But it actually doesn't call it for mapping.

I have my "web.xml" and "dispatcher-servlet.xml" located in "WEB-INF" folder and no extra configuration defined.

I got the feeling the problem is based on my project structure, but this is a basic eclipse "Dynamic Web Application", the tests are located in "src/test/java", parallel to "src/main/java".

I appreciate any help, since I spend last 2 hours on reading for solutions but not getting the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more time I got things right now:
There is still no way for me to access the dispatcher-servlet.xml in WEB-INF folder. I added a new "config" package to my test-package in parallel to my "controller" test package and put a copy of the dispatcher-servlet.xml in there, called "test-dispatcher-servlet.xml".

Now my test class is able to access this with

```
@ContextConfiguration("../config/test-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class HomeControllerTest {
```

Hope this can help others who start with spring mvc testing :-)